# How do I manually change a file name in Parcel?

Tags: javascript, npm, parceljs

Every time I try to run `npm start` or `npm build` I get an error saying `unknown: Entry /mnt/c/Users/kabre/Desktop/18-forkify/index.html does not exist`. I got told that Parcel might be automatically renaming my index.html. Not sure how to go on about fixing this since I'm just starting out learning Parcel/npm.

Comment: Can you put your code in a repository in GitHub?

Comment: Here's the code from Github https://github.com/jonasschmedtmann/complete-javascript-course/tree/master/18-forkify/starter

Comment: Since the solution doesn't involve changing a file's name, and the problem wasn't actually a file name, maybe it would be more accurate to rename the question. I came here researching an actual naming related issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- Run *npm init -y* in your project
- Install parcel in your project: *npm install parcel-bundler --save-dev*
- Put this in your *package.json*:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel ./index.html",
  }
```

- Run *npm start* after this.

And will running perfect.

Find more in https://parceljs.org/getting_started.html